# cryptography through java.io.FilterInputStream and java.io.FilterOutputStream

Tags: java, cryptography, objectinputstream

I've used FilterInputStream and FilterOutputStream in my Java program to gain more control over the incoming and outgoing stream of object data, for throwing errors when an object size overflow, enable/disable encryption manually without creating new ObjectOutputStream or needing the client to reconnect. I've implemented Diffie hellman's algorithm for the key exchange, but I get `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 4D` error from the other side's `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` when shifting bytes by the key(shared secret key between client and server) and write it to the stream inside FilterOutputStream, by overriding it's `write` method:

```
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if(isEncryptionEnabled) {
            for(int i=off; i<off+len; i++) {
                b[i] = (byte) (b[i] + encryptionKey[i%keySize]);
            }
        }
        super.write(b, off, len);
    }
```

and for FilterInpuStream:

```
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int res = super.read(b, off, len);
        if(res > 0 && isEncryptionEnabled) {
            for(int i=off; i<off+len; i++) {
                b[i] = (byte) (b[i] - encryptionKey[i%keySize]);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: @JimGarrison encryptionKey[] is just an array of bytes that holds the key, when overflowed Java automatically mods to fit the byte.

Comment: @JimGarrison: It's mod 256 addition, which is reversible as shown in his second method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please do not call this 'encryption'. Your 'encryption' is so trivial, a 3 year old monkey could undo it. If I slap 2 lollypop sticks together with a spot of glue, I don't think it's fair to call it 'a bridge', either. It doesn't matter how fancypants your key exchange is, if you so much as start your letter with 'Hello!', I have your key. Look up how to use e.g. AES-256.
2. Unless the sender toggles between 'encrypted' and 'not encrypted' mode at the exact same moment that the receiver also toggles, it's obviously not going to work. So, unless you have a protocol where all data is wrapped in a packet that starts with an identifier indicating how large the packet is (or some other mechanism by which the receiver can figure out where the packet ends - they just see an endless stream of bytes otherwise), and whether it is encrypted or not, you can't 'toggle' encryption on a single stream, period.
3. `res` is not equal to `len`, or doesn't have to be. The `read()` call will read at least 1 byte (unless the stream is closed, in which case it reads none, and returns -1), and will never read more than `len` bytes, but it may read somewhere in between.
4. **crucially**, your crypto scheme fails unless the `i` is in sync, but it won't be, because there is absolutely no relationship between the two. The sender may send one chunk of 4096 bytes, and the receiver may receive it in 18 separate smaller steps. With i being 0 every time, you're looking up the wrong byte from your encryptionKey.

There are a million explanations for why your code doesn't work. Probably because there are multiple issues with it. #4 on its own is a showstopper already.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, as for your point #2, I achieved this by firstly starting with plain mode then sending a specific object as an instruction to start encryption/decryption after agreement. for point #1, how to implement AES-256 (with the toggle capability if possible) for `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`?